# Select info from previous row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

My table mixes (the interesting cols):

| id | article | ordenr | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10001 | 2024-01-01 |
| 2 | b | 10002 | 2024-01-03 |
| 3 | c | 10004 | 2024-01-02 |
| 4 | a | 10003 |  |

How do I get the previous article of `ordernr` based on start_date.
I have tried LAG and that works fine until I include the current ordernr (say 10004) then it just return NULL.

This works, I get a list with the correct previous article and ordernr.

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    article, ordernr,
    LAG(ordernr) OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS prev_ordernr,
    LAG(article) OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS prev_article
FROM 
    mixes
ORDER BY 
    start_date DESC
```

But then I want a specific row, and add: `where ordernr = '10004'`, it just returns NULL on in the `prev_article` and `prev_ordernr`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you show us the code that "isn't working"? That attempt works exactly as expected. What are you expected results here exactly?

Comment: Sounds like you might need to put `LAG` into a subquery and then filter afterwards. But if it's only one row then an `APPLY (SELECT TOP 1` might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could outer join the previous values.

**DATA USED**

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_mixes') is not null)
    DROP TABLE #tmp_mixes

CREATE TABLE #tmp_mixes (id int, article char(1), ordenr int, start_date datetime)

INSERT INTO #tmp_mixes
VALUES
(1, 'a', 10001, '2024-01-01'),
(2, 'b', 10002, '2024-01-03'),
(3, 'c', 10004, '2024-01-02'),
(4, 'a', 10003, null)
```

Something like:

```
SELECT
    m.article,
    m.ordenr,
    m.start_date,
    prev.ordenr AS prev_ordernr,
    prev.article AS prev_article
FROM #tmp_mixes m
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1
        ordenr, article
    FROM #tmp_mixes prev 
    WHERE prev.start_date < m.start_date
    order by m.start_date desc
    ) prev
WHERE m.ordenr = 10004
order by m.start_date desc
```

**Results**

| article | ordenr | start_date | prev_ordernr | prev_article |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c | 10004 | 2024-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 10001 | a |

Answer (score 0):

I will use the create and populate table [done by Sterner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77976490/1501497), with thanks

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_mixes') is not null)
    DROP TABLE #tmp_mixes

CREATE TABLE #tmp_mixes (id int, article char(1), 
              ordernr int, start_date datetime)

INSERT INTO #tmp_mixes
VALUES
(1, 'a', 10001, '2024-01-01'),
(2, 'b', 10002, '2024-01-03'),
(3, 'c', 10004, '2024-01-02'),
(4, 'a', 10003, null)

select * from #tmp_mixes
```

and I will use LAG and LEAD as you originally did:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT article , ordernr,start_date, id,
           LAG(ordernr ) OVER (ORDER BY start_date )  lag_value,
           LEAD(ordernr ) OVER (ORDER BY start_date ) lead_value
    FROM #tmp_mixes
)
SELECT id, start_date, ordernr, 
lag_value AS prev_ordernr,
lead_value AS next_ordernr
FROM cte
ORDER BY  2
```

that gives me the following:

[image]

which I believe it is what you wanted.

However, it just doesn't stop there.The [lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

functions have now (since sql 2022 I think) parameters so that you can decided how you go on about `nulls`

```
LEAD ( scalar_expression [ , offset ] , [ default ] ) [ IGNORE NULLS | RESPECT NULLS ]
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )
```

Another way you could try is using [LAST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)